# Fix Can't perform a react state update on an unmounted component React native

Tags: javascript, react-native, expo, use-effect, setstate

how can I fix this error in my react native, see the code below.

**Warning: Can't perform a React state update on an unmounted component. This is a no-op, but it indicates a memory leak in your application. To fix, cancel all subscriptions and asynchronous tasks in a useEffect cleanup function.**

```
   const getData = () => {
        setIsLoading(true)
        axios.get(hosturl.loaduser + userlist.user_id + '&page=' +currentPage)
        .then((response) => {
            setEvent([...userData, ...response.data.data])
            setIsLoading(false)
        })
    }
  
    useEffect(() => {    
        getData();
    }, [currentPage]);
```

I did something like this see below but error keep showing.

```
useEffect(() => {   
    let isMounted = true;    
    if (isMounted) getData();    
    return () => { isMounted = false }; 
}, [currentPage]);
```

Answer (score 1):

```js
function MyComponent() {
    const mounted = useRef(false);

    const getData = () => {
      setIsLoading(true)
      axios.get(hosturl.loaduser + userlist.user_id + '&page=' +currentPage)
        .then((response) => {
          if (mounted.current) {
            setEvent([...userData, ...response.data.data])
            setIsLoading(false)
          }
        })
     }

    useEffect(() => {
        mounted.current = true;
        return () => {
            mounted.current = false;
        };
    }, []);

    useEffect(() => {     
      if (mounted.current) {
        getData();    
      }
    }, [currentPage]);

    return (
        ...
    );
}
```

The `useEffect()` hook, which should handle the `mounted` ref, is called when the component is mounted and sets the mutable `mounted.current` value to true. The return function from the `useEffect()` hook is called when the component is unmounted and sets the `mounted.current` value to `false`.

After that you can use the `mounted` ref (it's like a member variable in old style class components). I.e to get your data, only if your component is mounted, or set state in callback, only if component is mounted.

Comment: Hi @wuarmin thanks for your respond, what about `getData();` will I add it between `mounted.current = true;` and `return () => {mounted.current = false; };`

Comment: Check out the response. To fetch the data, you can create your own hook that will be called when the currentpage var changes.

Comment: Hi @wuarmin, I have since the response, but I notice there are two `useEffect` is that how it will work.

Comment: Let me say, I get this error want the data is loading more(Infinite scroll flatlist) and I click to another screen.

Comment: You are not limited to one `useEffect` hook. Every hook should have one responsibility. Do you already use the `mounted.current` in your request-callback (.then)?

Comment: Did you solve your issue?

Answer (score 1):

You could use axios Cancellation:

```
const controller = new AbortController();

const getData = () => {
   setIsLoading(true)
   axios.get(hosturl.loaduser + userlist.user_id + '&page=' +currentPage, {
    signal: controller.signal
   }).then((response) => {
       setEvent([...userData, ...response.data.data])
       setIsLoading(false)
    })
}
  
 useEffect(() => {    
    getData();
    
    return () => {
        controller.abort();
    };
 }, [currentPage]);
```

In this way you are aborting axios get on component unmount, avoiding `setEvent` and `setIsLoading` (and then the warning).

Comment: Hi @Giovanni Esposito, I tried it but did not work, it keep showing ActivityIndicator, not the fetch data, I get this error want the data is loading more and I click to another screen.